# Python Boolean Statement

Tags: java, python, boolean, expression

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ternary conditional operator in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/ternary-conditional-operator-in-python)

I've programmed in Java for quite sometime, I'm learning Python in school and I remember in Java for a boolean expression you could do

> boolean ? (if boolean is true this happens) : (if boolean is false this happens)

Is their a way to do the above Java code in Python? And what is the statement above properly called?

Comment: Related: [Ternary conditional operator in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/ternary-conditional-operator-in-python).

Comment: In the beggining Python did not include this, because it was thought such expressions would hinder readability. Being one of the few languages in wide use that does not inherit the C syntax  directly (like Java does), when they finally added this to Python, the idea was something that would be more naturally readable than the "C" way.  (The way to do it is in Martiin's answer bellow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use this (more pythonic):

```
>>> "foo"'if condition else "bar"
```

Or, this (more common, but not recommended):

```
>>> condition and "foo" or "bar"
```

Comment: *If* the latter is more common, it's just because the former was introduces a few version ago and a lot of existing code was written before that. It shouldn't be used at all by now.

Comment: The latter has huge problems if the right-hand expression of the `and` expression could evaluate to falshy (empty string, empty sequence, `None`, etc.)

Answer (score 10):

Yes, use a [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
somevalue if oneexpression else othervalue
```

Examples:

```
>>> 'foo' if True else 'bar'
'foo'
>>> 'foo' if False else 'bar'
'bar'
```

Before Python 2.5 where this was introduced, people used a combination of `and` and `or` expressions to achieve similar results:

```
expression and truevalue or falsevalue
```

but if the `truevalue` part of the expression itself evaluated to something that has the boolean value `False` (so a 0 or None or any sequence with length 0, etc.) then `falsevalue` would be picked *anyway*.

Answer (score 3):

Python:

```
x if condition else y
```

Example:

```
val = val() if callable(val) else val
greeting = ("Hi " + name) if name != "" else "Howdy pardner"
```

This is often called "the ternary operator" because it has three operands. However, the term "ternary operator" applies to *any* operation with three operands. It just happens that most programming languages don't have any other ternary operators, so saying "the" is unambiguous. However, I'd call it the `if/else` operator or a conditional expression.

In Python, due to the way the `and` and `or` operators work, you can also use them in some cases for things you'd usually use the ternary operator for in C-derived languages:

```
# provide a default value if user doesn't enter one
name = raw_input("What is your name? ") or "Jude"
print "Hey", name, "don't make it bad."

# call x only if x is callable
callable(x) and x()
```